# Error when I click on profile in setting in app

Tags: flutter

```
    import 'package:cached_network_image/cached_network_image.dart';
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

import '../models/user.dart';

class ProfileAvatarWidget extends StatelessWidget {
  final User user;
  ProfileAvatarWidget({
    Key key,
    this.user,
  }) : super(key: key);

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Container(
      padding: EdgeInsets.symmetric(vertical: 30),
      decoration: BoxDecoration(
        color: Theme.of(context).accentColor,
        borderRadius: BorderRadius.only(bottomLeft: Radius.circular(30), bottomRight: Radius.circular(30)),
      ),
      child: Column(
        children: <Widget>[
          Container(
            height: 160,
            child: Row(
              crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.center,
              mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceEvenly,
              children: <Widget>[
//              SizedBox(
//                width: 50,
//                height: 50,
//                child: MaterialButton(elevation:0,
//                  padding: EdgeInsets.all(0),
//                  onPressed: () {},
//                  child: Icon(Icons.add, color: Theme.of(context).primaryColor),
//                  color: Theme.of(context).accentColor,
//                  shape: StadiumBorder(),
//                ),
//              ),
                ClipRRect(
                  borderRadius: BorderRadius.all(Radius.circular(300)),
                  child: CachedNetworkImage(
                    height: 135,
                    width: 135,
                    fit: BoxFit.cover,
                    imageUrl: user.image?.url,
                    placeholder: (context, url) => Image.asset(
                      'assets/img/loading.gif',
                      fit: BoxFit.cover,
                      height: 135,
                      width: 135,
                    ),
                    errorWidget: (context, url, error) => Icon(Icons.error_outline),
                  ),
                ),
//              SizedBox(
//                width: 50,
//                height: 50,
//                child: MaterialButton(elevation:0,
//                  padding: EdgeInsets.all(0),
//                  onPressed: () {},
//                  child: Icon(Icons.chat, color: Theme.of(context).primaryColor),
//                  color: Theme.of(context).accentColor,
//                  shape: StadiumBorder(),
//                ),
//              ),
              ],
            ),
          ),
          Text(
            user.name,
            style: Theme.of(context).textTheme.headline5.merge(TextStyle(color: Theme.of(context).primaryColor)),
          ),
          Text(
            user.address,
            style: Theme.of(context).textTheme.caption.merge(TextStyle(color: Theme.of(context).primaryColor)),
          ),
        ],
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

======== Exception caught by widgets library =======================================================
The following assertion was thrown building SettingsWidget(dirty, dependencies: [_InheritedTheme, _LocalizationsScope-[GlobalKey#6d165]], state: _SettingsWidgetState#7b9f4):
A non-null String must be provided to a Text widget.
'package:flutter/src/widgets/text.dart':
Failed assertion: line 378 pos 10: 'data != null'
The relevant error-causing widget was:
SettingsWidget
file:///C:/Users/dell/Desktop/Tatkal%20app%20files/flutter_application/lib/route_generator.dart:96:50
When the exception was thrown, this was the stack:

1. #2      new Text (package:flutter/src/widgets/text.dart:378:10)
2. #3      _SettingsWidgetState.build (package:markets/src/pages/settings.dart:165:39)
3. #4      StatefulElement.build (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:4612:27)
4. #5      ComponentElement.performRebuild (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:4495:15)
5. #6      StatefulElement.performRebuild (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:4667:11)

## ...

Comment: some where the  data is going null

Comment: Please care to show your code.

Comment: Your error is in the file "profile.dart" on line #57. You were trying to create a text widget but the value inside is null.

Comment: how to resolve this error then? any suggestion?

Comment: Could you show the code for the class `S`,  where the about text is coming from. The error is `about` string is null when you are calling it.

Comment: updated the whole code.Let me know if you need more information to help me resolve the issue.

Comment: @VED where is whole code? I can't see anything new

Comment: @ProblematicDude check now

Comment: @VED problematic widget is `ProfileAvatarWidget(user: currentUser.value),` So show ProfileAvatarWidget

Comment: @ProblematicDude updated in code section

Answer (score 0):

I believe what's happening is that `user.name` is null or is not a String. So when you try to do `Text(user.name)`, an error is thrown. To see if this is indeed the case, set a breakpoint and debug or just add `print(user.name)` in the build method, like so:

```
@override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    print(user.name);
    return Container(
      ...
```

Also, you should probably mark the `user` parameter as required in the constructor. This way your IDE will warn you if you forget to pass it.

Comment: @ambino it's not helping.

Answer (score 0):

#### `??` Operator

If you're not sure whether your `Text` widget is getting a value to display or null, you can use the `??` operator to provide a fallback value in case the object on left is null.

```
Text(user?.name ?? 'Missing')
```

Comment: no its not making any difference, still the same error.

Comment: @VED Just double checking, you made the edit inside `SettingsWidget` `StatefulWidget`, right?  That's where the error is located according to your error copy/paste.  The code snippet in your question shows `ProfileAvatarWidget`, a `StatelessWidget`.